# Can anybody give me a example of how to licensing a software that use components from other software?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I wrote a software that used some pieces code from other software under a little modification. I'm confused by those copy right term and license term. Where should I put those copyright or license statement?

Here is the detail, there are three project called A, B and C. 
A use LGPL license.
B use no license but put some copyright statement in a file called LICENSE.
C use neither license nor copyright statement. It only write a line indicating author.

I took pieces of code from those projects and modified them (I only took some functions actually). So what should I do?

I already checked other questions. They said putting a file called LICENSE into root directory would be enough. But what should I do with that file?

Can anybody help? 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`LICENSE`** file will contain information on what kind of license your code is using.

This license should not violate any terms in the license of A,B or C(which you should stay away from as it doesn't have a license) as Jeff Atwood explains:

> Because I did not explicitly indicate a license, I declared an implicit copyright without explaining how others could use my code. Since the code is unlicensed, I could theoretically assert copyright at any time and demand that people stop using my code. Experienced developers won't touch unlicensed code because they have no legal right to use it.
>
> Without a license, the code is copyrighted by default. People can read the code, but they have no legal right to use it. To use the code, you must contact the author directly and ask permission.

source: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/pick-a-license-any-license.html

---

As far as mentioning the projects(A/B/C) from which you have taken code from goes, it is only necessary if the license of A/B/C requires you to do so.

A sample `LICENSE` file template:

> **project_name** by **author**
>
> This file is part of **project_name**. **project_name** is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>   (at your option) any later version.
>
> **project_name** is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>   GNU General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with **project_name**.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learnt a lot. But there is another question. Do  those license really have legal effect(or maybe, only in western country)? What if some developers violated license?

Comment: Let's take the example of GGPL.
**Only the individual copyright holders have the authority to sue when a license violation takes place**. So unless you are taking code from someone you think has the time to take you to court for stealing a function, there's nothing much to worry about as far as I see. But I'm no lawyer. And it is good practice to credit people and include a license with your project should you intend to make it available publicly.

Comment: Yes, those licences have legal effect. They build upon what @kedar said: without a licence the code is 100% copyrighted, the license allows you to do some things, what things? Exactly that which is stated in the licence, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thank you again. So, those licenses is more like moral standards which most developer would like to follow. Am I right?

Comment: It's much more than moral standards, it decides how someone's work can or can not be used in some other project, and how code can be distributed.